# How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube

In my iOS application I need to support the upload of videos to YouTube.

Is it possible to upload a video to YouTube within this application? If so, how can I implement this?

Comment: Here is an article where you can find example source code for iOS: http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/

Comment: Got the solution after a lot of search ....Use this link to download the sample code...100% working !! Set developer key and it will start working.The link https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion

Comment: don't lie, its not working for iphone

Comment: Try this link: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/

Comment: @Nirbhay GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib is missing on 3.3 step in source folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. There an API for it

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos

Comment: It only gives me error 400 Invalid Request responses. Can you post some code how to construct a valid request for direct uploading?