# upload video on youtube (only video not an url of the video) in ios

Tags: ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

i am doing an iphone app in which i wanna upload real time video to you tube.i am very new to iphone. so please guide me. tanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdata APIs Objective-C Client Library. You can download the code here : http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list