# Upload video to YouTube using iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, post, youtube

In my iPhone application I want to upload video file to YouTube.

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)