# How to upload video to youtube?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

Is there any way to implement functionality to upload video in youtube in iPhone? If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Video upload to YouTube is built into the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [Youtube API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos) and check the GDATA Objective-C Client [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/), also see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065628/uploading-video-with-iphone).