# Way to upload video on youtube using ios sdk

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

Can we upload video on youtube using ios sdk ?

I have sample code to upload with Gdata.I know using Gdata.

Are there any other way ? I have searched but not getting way other than Gdata.

Please reply if any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: @Brad Larson, Check my question first. I have asked way to upload except through GData. I don't think its duplicate, Well Its ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [link and documentation of the GDATA](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Uploading_Videos)

Download [GData Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) client and open its project in XCode

Below [link for the implementing the library STEPS](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. We must need user's gmail id/ password. Right ? OR is it possible without it ?

Comment: hi i want to upload video, can  you help me...

Comment: Try this: http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/