# Getting Youtube video viewCount Youtube API v3 / Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, youtube

I'm trying to get the view counts for Youtube videos.

```
"snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "tags": [
      string
    ],
    "categoryId": string,
    "liveBroadcastContent": string,
    "defaultAudioLanguage": string
  },

  "statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
```

This is the JSON that needs parsing.  I found a tutorial online with `snippet` correctly parsed like so:

```
performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in
            if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil {
                // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary object.
                let resultsDict = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                // Get all search result items ("items" array).
                let items: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                // Loop through all search results and keep just the necessary data.
                for var i=0; i<items.count; ++i {
                    let snippetDict = items[i]["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
//                    let statisticsDict = items[i]["statistics"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                    // Create a new dictionary to store the video details.
                    var videoDetailsDict = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
                    videoDetailsDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                    videoDetailsDict["channelTitle"] = snippetDict["channelTitle"]
                    videoDetailsDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]
                    videoDetailsDict["videoID"] = (items[i]["id"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["videoId"]
//                    videoDetailsDict["viewCount"] = statisticsDict["viewCount"]

                    // Append the desiredPlaylistItemDataDict dictionary to the videos array.
                    self.videosArray.append(videoDetailsDict)
```

You can see my attempts at trying to get the statistics data by doing the some type of parsing shown here for `snippet` but I have no luck, the result is alway nil for "viewCount" in `videoDetailsDict`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should start changing your dictionary declarations from  Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> to  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Comment: make sure `targetURL` contains `statistics` in the part

Comment: `var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,statistics&q=\(searchBar.text)&type=video&maxResults=15&key=\(apiKey)"`  doesn't work.  Do you have to do the GETs separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use YouTube API V3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290483/how-to-use-youtube-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `statistics` in the `part` parameter as follows:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet%252Cstatistics&id=QJYMdGpJQFs&_h=10&

Plus, if you want just the video count(or any specific info) I recommend you to use the `fields` parameter to make a smaller and clearer response.

i.e getting just the `viewCount` with `fields=items/statistics(viewCount)`
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet%252Cstatistics&id=QJYMdGpJQFs&fields=items%252Fstatistics(viewCount)&_h=5&