# Uploading a video to youtube from my swift app

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, vimeo, vimeo-ios

I've been asked to integrate videos into an existing app which previously only let users upload posts with images.

I don't want to host the videos on my own server for the following reasons:

- Server Bandwidth
- File Size Limits and Storage Space
- Slow-Loading Video or Unexpected Pauses During Playback
- Issues with converting to specific formats
- Piracy

Based off this article:

https://www.wp101.com/10-reasons-why-you-should-never-host-your-own-videos/

So I tried to research into where I could host the files and then I would simply have to store the URL in my db and use a video player to stream the content.

Vimeo and youtube seemed to be the main options I could find.

I'm wondering how best to implement, would I make use of a youtube API and on successful upload, grab the link and upload to my own server? I'm concerned this may be a long process for the end user.

Another problem is I can't see any swift examples (ZERO obj-c experience) of making the http request but perhaps it is still possible but I'd just have to write the code myself? I'm wondering if anyone has implemented anything like this already as I can't find any examples.

Looking at this question:

[How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

None of the links in the comments work and the answer directs to the youtube 2.0 API and I'm concerned that this is now deprecated.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Hi, this question ultimately is too broad for the scope of the site; it's asking for best practices, opinions, and for a general how-to guide for uploading videos to YouTube in Swift. If you can present a specific, objectively answerable question, preferably about code you've already written, it might salvage this question.

Comment: Check out the official Vimeo iOS Upload SDK: https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoUpload

Comment: check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053431/upload-video-to-youtube-in-swift