# How to get youtube videos list in IOS objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm using youtube data API v3 to make app like youtube for IOS in Objective-C.

successfully used YouTube IFrame Player API with video ID

Now i want to get youtube Home video List to show my IOS application home screen.
At first i don't want to show playlist or any thing else just want to show Home video list of youtube like this when we open youtube we see a list.

https://www.youtube.com/

If any one now how can i do this and what will be the parameters for API call?
If any one can share any example code thats very help full Thanks.

my code

```
NSString *url=@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities";

NSString *apiKey=@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"part": @"snippet",
                             @"home": @"true",
                             @"key" : apiKey
                             };



[manager GET:url
  parameters:parameters
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         // code
          NSLog(@"response");
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         /// code
          NSLog(@"err");
     }];
```

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&contentdetails&q={search key}&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&key={your api key}&maxResults=25        you can get videos by search key!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use YouTube API V3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290483/how-to-use-youtube-api-v3)