# Youtube iOS Helper Not playing videos in playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the methods below in my code.

```
(void)cuePlaylistByPlaylistId:(nonnull NSString *)playlistId
                      index:(int)index
               startSeconds:(float)startSeconds
           suggestedQuality:(YTPlaybackQuality)suggestedQuality;

(void)loadPlaylistByPlaylistId:(nonnull NSString *)playlistId
                       index:(int)index
                startSeconds:(float)startSeconds
            suggestedQuality:(YTPlaybackQuality)suggestedQuality;
```

I need help as the above methods are not playing and not giving any callback.
 Please help me out.

Comment: Try not setting the index because there is a reported [issue](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/287) that video doesn't play while setting index. You can also check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42813101/5995040) for workaround though it is a legacy code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Rebot.