# create playlist in Youtube api

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've looked at Youtube's documentation but I don't seem to understand how to create a playlist for the user specifically for ios. I know the user needs to sign in using OAuth 2 to grant apps access/authority to create a playlist

Documentation link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#uploaded_videos

But then given this code:

```
POST {base_URL}/playlists?part=snippet
 Request body:
{
'snippet': {
  'title': 'New playlist', 
  'description': 'Sample playlist for Data API',
 }
}
```

I'm not sure how to translate this to work on ios. How would I reflect the Request body object in objective c?

-------Update-----
Would it just be using NSURLSessionUploadTask? so I can send a post request and also send a dictionary for the request body? sry, a bit new to the IOS space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is update!

Client library from Google was updated.

Documentation: [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Playlist documentation: [Playlists: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert)

GitHub client library: [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C For REST](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest)

Here are pods need to be install:

```
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher'
pod 'GTMOAuth2'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube’
```

If we think  that we have clientID, clientSecret and scope (read documentation) then we can create viewController for authentication:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                                                    initWithScope:scope
                                                    clientID:kMyClientID
                                                    clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                    keychainItemName: nil
                                                    completionHandler:
                                                    ^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {
                                                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                                                        if (!error)
                                                        {
                                                            GTLRYouTubeService *youTubeService = [[GTLRYouTubeService alloc] init];
                                                            youTubeService.authorizer = auth;
                                                            [self createPlaylistWithTitle: @"Title" description: @"description" youtubeService: youtubeService];
                                                        }
                                                    }];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Method that creates private playlist:

```
- (void)createPlaylistWithTitle:(NSString *)playlistTitle description:(NSString *)playlistDescription youtubeService:(GTLRYouTubeService *)youTubeService
{
    GTLRYouTube_Playlist *playlist = [[GTLRYouTube_Playlist alloc] init];

    GTLRYouTube_PlaylistSnippet *playlistSnippet = [[GTLRYouTube_PlaylistSnippet alloc] init];
    playlistSnippet.title = playlistTitle;
    playlistSnippet.descriptionProperty = playlistDescription;

    GTLRYouTube_PlaylistStatus *playlistStatus = [[GTLRYouTube_PlaylistStatus alloc] init];
    playlistStatus.privacyStatus = @"private";

    playlist.snippet = playlistSnippet;
    playlist.status = playlistStatus;

    GTLRYouTubeQuery_PlaylistsInsert *query = [GTLRYouTubeQuery_PlaylistsInsert queryWithObject:playlist part:@"snippet,status"];
    [youTubeService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"response: %@", object);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you need to grant apps access to create a playlist by using  [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). It is generally a best practice to request scopes incrementally at the time access is required rather than up front.

Here's a code snippet how to create a playlist via YouTube API in IOS:

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
initWithScope:scope
clientID:clientId
clientSecret:clientSecret
keychainItemName:keychainItemName
completionHandler:
^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
[SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
} else {
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [FZMYoutubeSearchService sharedYoutubeService];
service.authorizer = auth;

GTLYouTubePlaylist *playlist = [[GTLYouTubePlaylist alloc] init];

GTLYouTubePlaylistSnippet *playlistSnippet = [[GTLYouTubePlaylistSnippet alloc] init];
playlistSnippet.title = @"this is my great playlist";
playlistSnippet.descriptionProperty = @"and this is description";

GTLYouTubePlaylistStatus *playlistStatus = [[GTLYouTubePlaylistStatus alloc] init];
playlistStatus.privacyStatus = @"private";

playlist.snippet = playlistSnippet;
playlist.status = playlistStatus;

GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube    queryForPlaylistsInsertWithObject:playlist part:@"snippet,status"];
[service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,      id object, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
```

Comment: Where did FZMYoutubeSearchService and GTLYouTubePlaylist come from? I can't seem to find them online