# Youtube iOS Creating Playlist Unauthorised

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I followed this stack overflow question: [create playlist in Youtube api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927062/create-playlist-in-youtube-api)

However when I make the request it gives the error unauthorised. 
I set the scope as kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeYoutubepartner and also tried kGTLRAuthScopeYouTube. I also implemented the project in swift but I feel my implementation is correct. I do not have a client secret though:

```
let clientID = "my_client_id"
        if let loginvc = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: kGTLRAuthScopeYouTube, clientID: clientID, clientSecret: "", keychainItemName: nil, completionHandler: { (vc, auth, error) in
            vc?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            if error == nil {
                self.youtubeService.authorizer = auth
                self.createYoutubePlaylistWithTitle("Name", { (id) in
                    print(id)
                })
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }) {
            self.present(loginvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

This is the createYoutubePlaylistWithTitle function:

```
func createYoutubePlaylistWithTitle(_ title : String,_ completion : @escaping (String) -> Void ) {
    let playlist = GTLRYouTube_Playlist()

    let playlistSnippet = GTLRYouTube_PlaylistSnippet()
    playlistSnippet.title = title

    let playlistStatus = GTLRYouTube_PlaylistStatus()
    playlistStatus.privacyStatus = "private"

    playlist.snippet = playlistSnippet
    playlist.status = playlistStatus

    let query = GTLRYouTubeQuery_PlaylistsInsert.query(withObject: playlist, part: "snippet,status")
    youtubeService.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, id, error) in
        if error == nil {
            //success
            if let playlistOut = id as? GTLRYouTube_Playlist {
                let playlistid = playlistOut.identifier!
                completion(playlistid)
            }
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check the [Youtube iOS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/ios) as it discusses the setup you to do before making calls to the Youtube API.

Comment: I look at the Quickstart guide and even using that when I try to insert a new playlist I still get unauthorised, even though I have the correct scope. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was that my google account wasn't setup with youtube - I didn't have a channel and therefore I couldn't make a playlist ... really annoying and dumb mistake that had me racking my brains for hours.